# Wildfly 10.1.0 getting "anonymous" as principal name in EJB

Tags: wildfly

Problem Statement: `context.getCallerPrincipal().getName()` always gives "anonymous" with following client and server settings

I have done all the settings required. My security domain is using a Custom spring security module for JAAS login. The client acts as an installer for the application. The main application is deployed on wildfly 10.1 and installer launches as a standalone application which access the remote EJBs from the server. The EJB access is successfully but when I access caller principle from context it always gives "anonymous"

**Client Side Settings:**

jboss-ejb-client.properties:

```
    remote.connections=default
    remote.connection.default.port=8080
    remote.connection.default.host=127.0.0.1
    remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
    remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
    remote.connection.default.username=root
    remote.connection.default.password=catch22*
```

Initial Context Creation:

```
    Properties prop1 = new Properties();
    prop1.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    prop1.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", "true");

System.out.println("setup()  ################### 1");
context = new InitialContext(prop1);
```

Used jboss-client.jar

I have used the jboss-client.jar lib provided with in "WILDFLY_HOME/bin/client" directory

**Server Side Settings**

ejb realm:

Added following ejb realm in standalone-full.xml

```
    <security-realm name="ejb-outbound-realm">
        <server-identities>
            <secret value="Q29ubmVjdGlvblBhc3N3b3JkMSE="/>
        </server-identities>
    </security-realm>
```

remoting subsystem settings:added out bound connection as follows

```
    <outbound-connections>
        <remote-outbound-connection name="ejb-outbound-connection" outbound-socket-binding-ref="ejb-outbound" security-realm="ejb-outbound-realm" username="root">
            <properties>
                <property name="SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS" value="false"/>
                <property name="SSL_ENABLED" value="false"/>
            </properties>
        </remote-outbound-connection>
    </outbound-connections>
```

Against out bound connection I have added following socket binding group

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="ejb-outbound">
    <remote-destination host="localhost" port="8080"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

application-users.properties:

```
root=7c5b7db204cb436044a4148094ef152e
```

application-roles.properties:

No change in this file

Session Bean Changes

```
@Stateless
@Local(AbstractEnterpriseSessionFacadeLocal.class)
@Remote(AbstractEnterpriseSessionFacadeRemote.class)
@SuppressWarnings({WarningConst.UNCHECKED, "rawtypes"})
@PermitAll
//@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.SecurityDomain("acegi-simple")
public class AbstractEnterpriseSessionFacadeBean<T, E extends IGeneralObject> implements AbstractEnterpriseSessionFacade {

injection of context in above class

@Resource
    private transient SessionContext context;
```

After above settings, when I am calling `context.getCallerPrincipal().getName()` it always gives me "anonymous"

Please help!

Comment: Have you got any solution for this??Even i am facing same issue

Comment: I solved the issue with adding the security domain 
@SecurityDomain("YOUR-DOMAIN")